# Error "Ruby isn't present" after upgrading from 3.0 to 3.7

Tags: silverstripe

So I upgraded everything by composer and the page seams to stopped working. I get this strange error saying that i don't have Rails. Here it is:

> [User Error] Compass Error:Ruby isn't present. The "ruby" command
>   needs to be in the webserver's path GET /admin/pages/edit/show/10 Line
>   98 in /var/www/demo/site/compass/code/Compass.php

Any ideas how to disable Compass or at least stop ir from compiling?

Comment: You could delete it - the core doesn't use compass any more

Comment: @RobbieAverill I tried to rename it but it gives another error. I guess it is somewhere in autoload files.

Comment: Hi Matiss, I've just installed a fresh 3.0.14 project and can't find `compass/code/Compass.php` in it. Do you have other modules installed, or custom project code that could be causing this?

Comment: hadnt installed any packages. Could compass be added because i installed 3.0 dev version? i see that silverstripe/compass ir required in composer.json along with silverstripe/docsviewer.

Comment: Right- can you simply delete the compass directory then? It’s not required in 3.7

Comment: i renamed the folder, removed compass from comoser, ran composer install regenerated autoload files and it seam to start work, except now i have ?stage=Stage param in all frontend urls. Is that normal?